# Can I use Piwik to track which pages or articles of PDF users opened?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, analytics, matomo

I would like Piwik to record which pages of 8-page PDF are read by users. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can only track which PDF file has been downloaded but you cannot inject HTTP-tracking-requests into the PDF file itself. You might consider putting links inside the PDF files which you would be able to track again as soon as they are clicked.